# Why does my vba loop skip to my outer next every time?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So I have a double loop that for some reason always skips to my outer loop for some reason. The loop goes from:

`For j = lastColumn To 6 Step (-1)`

to:

`Next i`

every single time. However, in my data set there's a mixed variety of data which should be captured in my if statement and count the data.

Any ideas? Maybe I formatted the macro wrongly.

```
Sub CheckDates()


Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


Sheets(1).Select

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'have to keep data in a table for this to actually work as it ctrls+left to the table, which will end where the very last text of any row is
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column


count = 0
i = 3
j = lastColumn

For i = 3 To lastrow
    For j = lastColumn To 6 Step (-1)
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) < Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) And Sheet1.Cells(i, j - 1) = "Reçu" Then
        count = count + 1
    GoTo NextIteration
        End If
    Next j
    NextIteration:
Next i

Sheet2.Cells(1, 7) = count

Sheets(2).Select


'Runs the DeleteSAC Macro
Call DeleteSAC

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped though this in the debugger? What value are you getting for `lastColumn`?

Comment: You have so many sheet identifiers:Sheets(1), Sheet1, Sheets(2), Sheet2, Activesheet. Who is who? Are those only 2 sheets? Does your Visual Basic recognize the french C letter? and the 3 lines starting with count = 0 are usless. Try to invent another name for count. Why are you counting backwards?

Comment: The problem you are having with your loop is that you use `GoTo NextIteriation` within your `j` loop which jumps to the next `i` before your `j` loop is completed. Comment out your  `GoTo` and `NextIeration:` then see what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow what you're doing, but try this instead. Notice the `Exit For`. This should produce the result you're looking for, without the For-Next counter variables getting confused.

```
For i = 3 To lastrow
    For j = lastColumn To 6 Step (-1)
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) < Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) And Sheet1.Cells(i, j - 1) = "Reçu" Then
            count = count + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks,  however, I don't want to actually exit the entire loop. I even tried it and it doesn't help as for some reason the loop goes directly from  For j = lastColumn To 6 Step (-1)  ----- To Next i --- as I've mentioned in my question. So that doesn't seem to be the problem!

Comment: Isn't that functionally identical to the OP's code? The loop counters reinitialize when they get looped over by the `i` loop.

Comment: So the IF statement seems to always evaluate as true..? If so, you might test it by breaking the two expressions into a nested If-Then to perhaps determine which of them is the issue. So `If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) < Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) And Sheet1.Cells(i, j - 1) = "Reçu" Then` would become `If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) < Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) Then If Sheet1.Cells(i, j - 1) = "Reçu" Then` with another `Endif` After the `Exit For`.

Answer (score 0):

## Simplification

Use **Long** for rows, and **Integer** for columns.

When you write **`With Sheet1`**, everywhere where you should write `Sheet1`, e.g. `Sheet1.Range(whatever)...` you can write just `.Range(whatever)` instead, until you close with **End With**.

The **Exit For** exits only the For Loop where it is in. So it does exactly what you are doing with your **Goto** line, but you are using a line more.

When you use Sheet1 or Sheet2 etc. you are actually using code names so you can change the names in the tab and the code will still run.

Counting backwards is usually used when you delete row by row so there is no need to do so since you are only counting.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckDates()

    Dim dataCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long

    With Sheet1
        
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        'have to keep data in a table for this to actually work as it ctrls+left
        'to the table, which will end where the very last text of any row is
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 3 To lastrow
            For j = 6 To lastColumn
                If .Cells(i, j) < Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) And .Cells(i, j - 1) = "Reçu" Then
                    dataCount = dataCount + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
    
    End With
    
    With Sheet2
        .Cells(1, 7) = dataCount
        .Select
    End With
    
    'Runs the DeleteSAC Macro
    DeleteSAC

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to exit the loop when the `If` statement is true. I think he is wanting to continue the `j` loop for multiple trues that can be on each row. I think the `Goto` was the OP not understanding what `Next j` does. That said; good code. +1